# Looking for duplicated values in an array for a certain key

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sku_code_part_id] => 1
            [part_label] => blue
            [part_value] => BLU
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sku_code_part_id] => 2
            [part_label] => Orange
            [part_value] => ORG
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sku_code_part_id] => 3
            [part_label] => Orange
            [part_value] => ORG
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sku_code_part_id] => 4
            [part_label] => Orange
            [part_value] => ORG
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [sku_code_part_id] => 5
            [part_label] => Green
            [part_value] => GRE
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [sku_code_part_id] => 6
            [part_label] => Red
            [part_value] => RED
        )

)
```

I'm wanting a simple way of checking the array $this->request->post['custom_parts'] for the any duplicated values assigned to the part_value keys.

So I can flag an error that 'ORG' is duplicated numerous times.

I've tried various methods such as removing duplications and comparing before and after. However I'm running into a number of issues with this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use "array_key_exists"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: Not sure how that would work, as i'm looking if the value of 'part_value' exists more than once. Not just once.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to write a function but here is a solution using foreach.

```
$part_values = [];
$part_values_duplicates = [];
foreach($this->request->post['custom_parts'] as $customPart){
    if(!in_array($customPart['part_value'], $part_values)){
        $part_values[] = $customPart['part_value'];
    }
    else {
        $part_values_duplicates[] = $customPart['part_value'];
    }
}
var_dump($part_values_duplicates);
```

Comment: Edit : There was a type in $part_values_duplicates inside the var_dump(); (Last line)